# How do I get these two buttons and the field to be on the same line?

Tags: html, css

How do I get the buttons and the field on the same line?

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is my HTML

```
<td class="book-mid" style="width:48%;">
    <div class="book-invoice-updown">
        <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:36px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceDelLine($index);">
            <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">arrow_upwards</md-icon>
        </button>
        <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:36px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceDelLine($index);">
            <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">arrow_downwards</md-icon>
        </button>
        <input type="text" ng-model="invoiceLines.lineText"  id="lineText" class="book-field book-field-slim">
    </div>
</td>
```

This is my `book-invoice-updown` class

```
.book-invoice-updown {
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This ended up being my solution, now it scales nicely to all devices:

```
<td class="book-mid nowrap" style="width:48%;">
    <table style="width:100%"><tr>
        <td style="width:10%; vertical-align:middle;">
            <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:32px; margin-right:2px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceLineUp($index);">
                <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Up">arrow_upwards</md-icon>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:10%; vertical-align:middle;">
            <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:32px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceLineDown($index);">
                <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Down">arrow_downwards</md-icon>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td style="width:80%; vertical-align:middle;">
            <input type="text" ng-model="invoiceLines.lineText" id="lineText" class="book-field book-field-slim">
        </td>
    </tr></table>
</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help greatly if you posted the rest of your HTML and CSS (in a snippet and a fiddle), to give a bigger picture.

To begin you can get rid of excess browser-added margins and padding by adding 
`*{margin:0; padding:0;}` at the top of your CSS file. This way whatever margin and padding you set in the subsequent rules will be accurate.

Also , you could use `vertical-align` to align your elements in the rows of the table (middle or top - I use middle more often) . This may make the elements display closer to what you're after.

(By the way, to inspect an element, right-click on the page and choose 'Inspect' - that's one way! there are extensions you can use like Firebug etc to inspect your code.)

Comment: I did a lot of inspections, set margin and padding to 0, vertical-aligned everything and when I finally got them to align (by setting a width on the field) they lost the ability to scale properly. So I solved them with a table instead (I put the HTML up in my question)

Comment: @torbenrudgaard wonderful! happy to be of assistance :) scalabilty can be solved by media queries most likely (as opposed to having to use a table) p.s. looks beautyful ;)

Comment: Yes but its to much damn work with media queries. I think the road ahead instead would be Flexbox, that looks very strong! w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: @torbenrudgaard i know about flexbox. You should still look into media queries, they aren't hard and not exactly what i'd call too much trouble; in any case they're good to know

Answer (score 1):

I think adding `vertical-align: middle;` to your CSS rules for the buttons/input should get them all to line up the way you want them to.

See this tutorial on w3schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

```css
.book-invoice-updown {
    display: inline-block; 
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
.book-invoice-updown button, .book-invoice-updown input {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-invoice-updown">
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:36px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceDelLine($index);">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">arrow_upwards</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button class="book-button book-text-button col-std-money" style="max-width:36px;" ng-click="vm.invoiceDelLine($index);">
        <md-icon class="material-icons book-material" aria-label="Close">arrow_downwards</md-icon>
    </button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="invoiceLines.lineText"  id="lineText" class="book-field book-field-slim">
</div>
```

It may also be that your input or buttons have a 'float' property or some other things affecting their alignments. It will be easier to diagnose if you provide a simple, complete code sample where we can see the issue reproduced.

Answer (score 1):

When I test this, all elements are `display: inline`.

That said, you do have several other buttons and inputs displayed. I imagine you probably also have different style settings for those. I would use your browser's "Inspect Element" feature (part of its Developer Tools) to see what padding, margin, and borders are surrounding all your elements.

[Guide to Inspect Element](https://www.lifewire.com/get-inspect-element-tool-for-browser-756549).

Good luck.